# Spark streaming merge data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My understanding is that Spark Streaming serialises the closure (e.g. map, filter, etc) and executes it on worker nodes (as explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)). Is there some way of sending the results back to the driver program and perform further operations on the local machine?

In our specific use case, we are trying to turn the results produced by Spark into an observable stream (using RxScala).

Comment: All of the output operations on streams are shown here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams. If the predefined are not enough, then you should create your own output with foreachRDD.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but answering the question as-is would just duplicate what's on the docs. Could you narrow down your question to a specific usecase? Even better if you can add illustrative code to it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted a comment but deleted it afterwards. He suggested using `collect()` on an RDD. A simple test showed that collect gathers data from the worker nodes and executes on the driver node; exactly what I needed.